# Adding recessed lighting to room with ceiling fan/light already installed, and using fan will all the light off

Tags: electrical

I have 1 switch, that controls light of ceiling fan and fan is controlled by remote control.

However, I find the room quite dark, thus I want to add several led pot light.  I know this is possible.

During summer season room get quite warm, thus at night, I want to use the fan and turn all the light off,

Is this possible without running a new electrical line?

Comment: Does the fan work when the switch is off?

Comment: At a minimum you likely are going to have to run some wire from the fan light to the new boxes

Comment: No,  Fan does not work when lights off.  Usually, I would turn on the switch, and use a remote controller turn off fanlight.

Comment: It can be done with smart lights a bit expensive but the lights can be turned off and the fan will still work but you will need to run new wires from the fan junction box if there is attic access this would be an easy DIY project.

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this a few years ago, except I had no ceiling light or fan.  I ran a 14/3 up from the wall switch that only powered the outlets.  Since I was also adding cans, I used the 6“ holes I drilled as  access to run the wires, both up the wall and between joists.

I also cut out the original junction box for the wall switch and added an old construction box, having the box removed allowed me access to drill into the top plate.  Using rare earth magnets tied to a string, I was able to stick the magnet to the bit and then pull the string back.  Then use the string to pull the wire.